# Parse a File To Get Set Of Words - May Be NLP Related?

Tags: python, nlp

I want to parse a file that is between 300-2,000 words and create lists of words in groups of 1 to n words long. For example, if I had this file:

```
 The fat cat sat on a mat.
```

The output for 1-2 would be:

```
# group of words, 1 word length
['The' 'fat' 'cat' 'sat' 'on' 'a' 'mat'] 

 # group of words, 2 word length
 [['The', 'fat'], ['fat'], 'cat', ['cat', 'sat'], ['sat', 'on'], ['on', 'a'], ['a', 'mat']]
```

I'm sure I could write some very inefficient code that could do this but I'm wondering if there is an NLP (or other) library that can do this for me.

Comment: Is `["fat"], "cat"` supposed to be `["fat", "cat"]`? In positions 2 and 3 of the output?

Answer (score 4):

In computational linguistics, we call them unigrams, bigrams, trigrams, etc., or n-grams in general. There is an `ngrams()` function in the [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/util.html#ngrams).

The first thing you need to do is tokenize, e.g., like this:

```py
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

# ['The', 'fat', 'cat', 'sat', 'on', 'a', 'mat', '.']
words = word_tokenize('The fat cat sat on a mat.')
```

Then you can get the ngrams like so:

```py
from nltk import ngrams

bigrams = list(ngrams(words, 2))
```

which will give you

```py
[('The', 'fat'), ('fat', 'cat'), ('cat', 'sat'), ('sat', 'on'), ('on', 'a'), ('a', 'mat'), ('mat', '.')]
```

Comment: Sweet!  Thanks so much